# Php isset inside an echo validation

Tags: php, html, echo, isset

Hi I want to check the following validation:

```
echo '<div id="msg"><?php echo isset($msg)?$msg:''; ?></div>';
```

I know that is wrong, what is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already within the PHP realm, you're running PHP.. you can't start another PHP. Also single quote `'` wont expand variables.
I'm running on a lot of assumptions from your project

Using your logic you could do this:

```
echo '<div id="msg">' . (isset($msg) ? $msg : '') . '</div>';
```

but it would be best to not just output the div when the variable isn't set

```
if(isset($msg)) {
    echo "<div id=\"msg\">$msg</div>";
}
```

More info on what you're trying to achieve would let me educate you more on best practices.

Your edit suggestion still has you trying to start a new php block within a php
block.

You suggested to edit my answer (which was weird) with this:

```
echo '<div class="container">
 <form action="includes/ajax.php" id="profilePictureUpload" class="dropzone">
   <div class="fallback">
     <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
   </div>
 </form>

 <h1>Gallery</h1>
 <div class="alert alert-warning my-2">
   <i class="fa fa-2x fa-exclamation-circle float-right"></i>
   <ol class="m-0">
     <li>Image uploading limit is 5.</li>
     <li>One image not more then 5MB.</li>
   </ol>
 </div>
  <div id="msg"><?php echo isset($msg)?$msg:''; ?></div>
 </div>';
```

If you had read what i posted, you need to replace that 1 `<div id="msg"...`  with what i posted. Did you check?

Comment: @HernâniPereira I really hope that `$msg` isn't provided from the user (even before inserting into a database). because it's an XSS vulnerability if it is.

Comment: @OliverO'Neill considering the HTML code it's more likely a message informing about the result of upload.